# Data Upload using REST

Tags: rest, caching, hadoop, storage, hdfs

I am developing a REST application that can be used as a data upload service for large file. I create chunks of the file and upload each chunk. I would like to have multiple services running this service (For load balancing). I would like my REST service to be a stateless system (No information about each stored chunk). This will help me avoid server affinity. If i allow server affinity, i can have a server for each upload request and the chunks can be stored in a temporary file in the disk and can be moved to some other place once the upload is complete.

Ideally i would use  a central place for the data to be stored. I would like to avoid this as this is a  single point of failure (bad in a distributed system). So i was thinking about using a distributed file system say like HDFS but appending to file is not very efficient and so this is not an option.

Is it possible to use some kind of a cache for storing the data? Since the size of the data is quite big (2 -3 GB files) traditional cache solutions like Memcache cannot be used.

Is there any other option to solve this problem. Am I not looking in any particular direction?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about any "system" providing these features. But you can use the idea of HDFS, which stores chunks of the file in several locations and when data are requested chunks are read in proper order and served to the client.